# When to use tensorflow estimators?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a general tensorflow question about when to use estimators. I feel sometimes estimators are not convenient to build something, since we need to meet some fixed requirements when building the graph. On the other hand, using lower level api can be tedious sometimes. Therefore, I want to ask when it is proper to use estimators and when it is not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very opinionated answer but I will still write it:

The Estimator-API was developed to simplify building and sharing models. You could compare it with Keras and in fact Estimators is built with `tf.keras.layers` so one could say it is a simplification of a simplification.

This is obviously good for beginners or people who come from other fields (as people working with ML often do) but can also delimit the things you can do.

As a general rule of thumb I would use Estimators if you want to work on or share a model with people that do not have a good CS background but want to get going either way.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the idea! For some complicated graphs like ResNet or GRU, do you think Estimators will be a good choice for people with some CS background?

Comment: You can always use the Estimators, just make sure you know what goes on under the hood. Debugging neural networks can be tough. And even tougher if you do not know the underlying ideas that make it work. This is what makes these simplifications dangerous. If you come to the point where you need to use the lower level API you will be glad to know what goes on.

Comment: So far, I felt that Tensorflow does not have a systematic tutorial materials yet. It is like many scattered pieces that I need to collect if I want to learn it well. When I need to know A, then I go to the official website and realize that I need to know B, C, D, ...